# Visual Studio 2013 Preview Not Responding frequently

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2013

I've installed the Visual Studio 2013 Preview to try out and I'm having some very bad performance issues.  Every time I open a file and immediately try to close it, edit a file, save a file, etc. the IDE will stop responding for about 15 seconds.

I've gone through every performance tweak I could find through stackoverflow, blogs, web search, etc but none have worked (for example, clean up temp folders, disable add-ins and extensions, delete .suo file, etc.).

Using /safemode, the performance problems go away but I can't find what could be different since I have no add-ins, nuget packages, or extensions installed.

Using SysInternals Process Explorer, I can only see the process for devenv.exe peg the core it's using at 100% when it stops responding.  I am not seeing any network or hard drive activity during this time and no other processes become active.

I've reinstalled with no luck, and I've installed it on another development machine where it seems to work just fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** In Process Explorer 'Other I/O Delta' shows ~200,000/sec when it locks up on the devenv.exe process.  Still looking...

**UPDATE 2:**  I guess I should add that this PC is a Dell Vostro 460, i7-2600 @ 3.4Ghz, 8GB RAM, Windows 7, 1TB HDD with 550GB free, plenty of power for what I'm doing.  Closed all other apps while debugging, including VIPRE A/V and Malwarebytes.

**UPDATE 3:**  Maybe getting closer... using Process Monitor (love SysInternals stuff!) for some reason my entire C:\Projects\ folder is being parsed/searched by devenv.exe.  I keep all my project folders under C:\Projects\ where there are about 20 projects each with their own sub-folder.  Here's where it gets weird.  In /safemode, devenv only parses the current project's folder, not the entire parent folder.  Projects has 6,271 folders with 29,914 files.  I tried creating a new c:\Projects2013\ folder, created a new test project, and devenv is trying to parse the full parent Projects2013 folder, yet in /safemode only parses Projects2013\Sample.

Obviously though the new project in Projects2013 runs full speed because it's parsing far fewer files.  The other computer runs fine because I left the default Projects path and there were no other projects in that folder.  Now what in the world could be doing this and why the different folder path between regular and safe mode?  Time to dig through Tools, Options... ugh!

Here's a screen grab from ProcMon:

[image: Other I/O activity for devenv.exe]

**Final Update - Resolved!**  It was git causing the problem.  I had a local repository set at c:\Projects\ which contained all my various project sub-folders.  The dump file I created for them allowed them to narrow it down to git.  Removing the local repository fixed my performance issue where VS 2013 is at least usable now.  The programming team still needs to resolve the continuous re-parse of the folder though.  Anyone with a very large repository will end up with this issue.

Comment: I sent some feedback to Microsoft, and now their support team wants to look at it.  Creating dump files and all that fun stuff.  May have found a bug.  We'll see!

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with the release version of Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.21005.1 REL). Did you get any further comments from MS? VS2013 with a Git repository is unusable for me at the moment (frequent stalls and high disk usage).

Comment: Also appears to take an AGE (>2mins) to create a new Blank Windows Store app project within a folder that contains a Git repository.

Comment: Mine was resolved by breaking things up into much smaller separate repositories.  Not really a fix but I haven't had an issue since and I am now using the full release of VS 2013 Premium.  You may want to try contacting the dev team.  I used the Feedback "Send a frown" built in to VS and they were very responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RESOLVED!**  It was git causing the problem. I had a local repository set at c:\Projects\ which contained all my various project sub-folders. The debug dump file I created for the VS programmers allowed them to narrow it down to git. Removing the local repository fixed my performance issue where VS 2013 is at least usable now. The VS programming team still needs to resolve the continuous re-parse of the folder though. Anyone with a very large repository will end up with this issue.

Comment: Btw I also raised this as an issue with Microsoft and their final response was "by design".

Comment: Can you give more information on how did you fixed it? I don't understand what you did

Comment: The problem was I had a one Git repository for the root folder of all my projects.  There were way too many files/folders for it to handle that way.  I created separate Git repos for each project and the problem goes away.  Essentially it's an issue of volume.